# Class library is not found while building the ASP.NET Core 7 Web API with Github Actions

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, continuous-integration, github-actions, class-library

I wrote this `dotnet.yml` to build my application and push the docker image to docker hub, placed in the root of [my project](https://github.com/Dezuranje-si/rso-user-service) under the folder `.github/workflows/`.

```
name: .NET Docker CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master # Replace with your default branch if it's not 'master'

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Docker Buildx
      uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

    - name: Log in to Docker Hub
      uses: docker/login-action@v1
      with:
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN }}

    - name: Build and push
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
      with:
        context: .
        file: ./RSOUserMicroServiceAPI/RSOUserMicroService/Dockerfile
        push: true
        tags: muchacho3alex/rsouserservice:latest
```

In the solution (root/SolutionFolder/) I have class library RSO.Core Project and an ASP .NET Core (7.0) Web API project (both in standalone folders) which reference the RSO.Core project as `"..\RSO.Core\RSO.Core.csproj"` with following Dockerfile which is located in the the same folder as the Web API project and successfully builds locally.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["RSOUserMicroService/RSOUserMicroService.csproj", "RSOUserMicroService/"]
COPY ["RSO.Core/RSO.Core.csproj", "RSO.Core/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./RSOUserMicroService/./RSOUserMicroService.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/RSOUserMicroService"
RUN dotnet build "./RSOUserMicroService.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./RSOUserMicroService.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Release
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RSOUserMicroService.dll", "--environment=Release"]
```

While executing this, I get two errors that indicate that my RSO.Core project is missing.

```
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref u5g15bo5195rycdxlwy3dcamk::qdmrc6j8wf03upivu1wypotf0: "/RSO.Core/RSO.Core.csproj": not found
Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref u5g15bo5195rycdxlwy3dcamk::qdmrc6j8wf03upivu1wypotf0: "/RSO.Core/RSO.Core.csproj": not found
```

How to exactly refence these projects to get a successful docker build and push to the dockerhub repository? Is anything needed to remove from some cache?

```
The repository structure:
(Root)
.github/workflows/dotnet.yml
Solution.sln
 -.dockerignore
 -.sln
 -RSO.Core Project
 --Logic
 --Repository
 --Models
 -Asp .Net Core Project
 --Controllers 
 --Dockerfile
```